# gaussian integral subject to a constraint

Tags: definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

How to evaluate $$\iiint_{plane}e^{-a(x^2+y^2+z^2)}dxdydz$$ subject to constraint $$lx+my+nz=0$$ where a,l,m,n are positive constants.

Comment: The integral doesn't (apparently) depend on the constraint. I do not understand your question. Are you just asking how to compute the line integral over the line $lx + my + nz = 0$?

Comment: I am introducing the constraint $$lx+my+nz=0$$ to the integral. x, y and z can't change arbitrarily. They have to satisfy the constraint equation. The constraint isn't a line so I cant say that it is a line integral.

Comment: No, it isn't a line. It is a plane passing through the origin and the normal of the plane is $\langle l, m, n\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's a plane. But the point still stands - a volume integral over a plane is always zero. I think you want to have a *surface* integral, in which case you can make a symmetry argument (because the integrand is a radial function) to realize that the value doesn't depend on the values of $l, m, n$.

Comment: Ok, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Radon transform of a Gaussian
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^3} e^{-a|\mathbf x|^2} \delta(\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf \theta - p) \text d\mathbf x
$$
where $\mathbf \theta = (l,m,n)$ and $p=0$.

For $a=1, |\theta| = 1$ the result is known to be $\pi e^{-p^2}$ which is independent from $\mathbf \theta$.  Straightforward changes of variables and homogeneity of Dirac's delta function will yield
$$
\frac{\pi}{a|\theta|}e^{-ap^2/|\theta|^2}
$$
which evaluates to $\pi/(a|\theta|)$ when $p=0$.